# Two methods in one scala

Tags: scala, methods, refactoring, field

Starting my first project with Scala: a poker framework.

So I have the following class

```
class Card(rank1: CardRank, suit1: Suit){
val rank = rank1
val suit = suit1
}
```

And a Utils object which contains two methods that do almost the same thing: they count number of cards for each rank or suit

```
def getSuits(cards: List[Card]) = {

def getSuits(cards: List[Card], suits: Map[Suit, Int]): (Map[Suit, Int]) = {
  if (cards.isEmpty)
    return suits

  val suit = cards.head.suit
  val value = if (suits.contains(suit)) suits(suit) + 1 else 1
  getSuits(cards.tail, suits + (suit -> value))

}

getSuits(cards, Map[Suit, Int]())

}


def getRanks(cards: List[Card]): Map[CardRank, Int] = {

def getRanks(cards: List[Card], ranks: Map[CardRank, Int]): Map[CardRank, Int] = {
  if (cards isEmpty)
    return ranks

  val rank = cards.head.rank
  val value = if (ranks.contains(rank)) ranks(rank) + 1 else 1
  getRanks(cards.tail, ranks + (rank -> value))
}

getRanks(cards, Map[CardRank, Int]())
}
```

Is there any way I can "unify" these two methods in a single one with "field/method-as-parameter"?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that would require high order function (that is, function that takes function as parameter) and type parameters/genericity

```
def groupAndCount[A,B](elements: List[A], toCount: A => B): Map[B, Int] = {
   // could be your implementation, just note key instead of suit/rank 
   // and change val suit = ... or val rank = ... 
   // to val key = toCount(card.head)
}
```

then

```
def getSuits(cards: List[Card]) = groupAndCount(cards, {c : Card => c.suit})
def getRanks(cards: List[Card]) = groupAndCount(cards, {c: Card => c.rank})
```

You do not need type parameter A, you could force the method to work only on Card, but that would be a pity.

For extra credit, you can use two parameter lists, and have

```
def groupAndCount[A,B](elements: List[A])(toCount: A => B): Map[B, Int] = ...
```

that is a little peculiarity of scala with type inference, if you do with two parameters lists, you will not need to type the card argument when defining the function :

```
def getSuits(cards: List[Card]) = groupAndCount(cards)(c => c.suit)
```

or just

```
def getSuits(cards: List[Card] = groupAndCount(cards)(_.suit)
```

Of course, the library can help you with the implementation

```
def groupAndCount[A,B](l: List[A])(toCount: A => B) : Map[A,B] =
   l.groupBy(toCount).map{case (k, elems) => (k, elems.length)}
```

although a hand made implementation might be marginally faster.

A minor note, Card should be declared a `case class` :

```
case class Card(rank: CardRank, suit: Suit) 
// declaration done, nothing else needed
```